# XCFramework or other binary from podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcframework

I've searched through bunch of questions and related topics on StackOverflow and other resources.

The main idea to have:

1. Properly working pod.
2. Some kind of binary (xcframework) that can be distributed through cocopods.

Pod user should be completely uninterested which version is attached (sources or binary).

What have been tried:

Pre-setup: Create project with framework target. Create `Podfile` with references 'sources pod'.

1. Set `use_frameworks!` flag in `Podfile`. Build XCFramework using `xcodebuild archive` and `xcodebuild -create-xcframework`. The result is almost empty xcframework without code inside.
2. Set `use_modular_headers!` flag in `Podfile`. Build XCFramework. The result is almost 27mb xcframework with code inside, but which cannot be used when included to other project.

What else I've tried:
  `s.module_map        = "MyFramework.modulemap"`

With following code inside. Looks like this modulemap is ignored with `s.vendored_frameworks` flags.

```
framework module MyFramework {
  module * { export * }
}
```

Plugin `cocoapods-packager` seems outdated.

Is there any convenient way to "package" existing pod?
Is there any way to make xcframework expose packages included?
Is there other way that xcframework I'm not familiar with, which will satisfy the criteria form "main idea"?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I'm dealing with similar situation: I did manage to install the xcframework pod into app, but when I created a modulemap (for allowing connection between internal ObjC & Swift classes) - it succeeded through Carthage & SPM but failed through Cocoapods.
Any solution how to add it with modulemap?